# Convert string to int in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Following is my piece of code in which I am assigning my screen width to variable `$width`. But when I convert it to integer and echo it, `0` is returned.

```
$width = '<script> document.write(window.screen.width); </script>';
//if i echo $width it shows 1366 which is width of my screen
$height = '<script> document.write(window.screen.height); </script>';
echo "The height is = $height"."<br>The width is = ".$width;
$a = (int)($width);
echo $a;
```

I am asking for guidenance to make this conversion perfect.

Comment: You're doing this the wrong way round - JS is executed on the client, not PHP. You're just assigning the script string to `$width`, which when cast to an integer is 0.

Comment: LOL, there is so much "wrong" here. PHP and Javascript execute at different times and places. PHP = Server, Javascript = Client

Comment: hope you are confused with serverside scripting and clientside scripting. You are trying to typecast string to integer where the string is not number.

Comment: @used2could I agree far too much with your first sentence for this to be healthy `:P`.

Comment: You could try jquery ajax, it's much easier http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: All i was trying to do is  to get screen size in my PHP variable. But now i'll keep one thing in mind never use javascript side ways with php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't actually getting the screen dimensions at that time. That runs on the client. You will have to make an ajax call to the server to set it.

Comment: is there a way to get screen width via PHP?

Comment: @softgenic no. PHP is **server-side**.

Comment: You can set a cookie (or use sessions) on the first run, and then PHP will have access to it. So if there's no cookie, run the JS part of the code and refresh the page. When it refreshes, you'll have the screed width in a cookie, the JS part will be skipped and the page will load normally.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use javascript to echo out a PHP variable. The javascript isn't executed until the PHP is LONG finsihed doing what it does. The best you can do with javascript is to ajax the data back, but that could only be used in a fresh PHP script - and not the current page.

You certainly can't expect data to come back before the script has finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

It would be [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) **but** what you are doing isn't possible because you cannot pass client data from the browser through to a php script without $_POST, $_GET, or the similar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need parantheses. Try `$a = (int) $width;` or `$a = intval($width);`.

Also, there is no sense in the code you are running.

```
$width = '<script> document.write(window.screen.width); </script>';
```

This will just set `$width` to be the string containing the HTML code (with the JavaScript inside). You can't fetch the return value of the JavaScript code that easily into a PHP variable, mainly because the JS part is executed **way after** the PHP is done (PHP is handled by the server, the generated HTML (with JS inside) is sent to the browser and the browser takes care of executing JS). To do that, you will need [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).